# Go-Sqlite3 cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

Tags: golang, компиляция, sqlite3

Не хочет компилировать `sqlite3` из этого репозитория *github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3*. Ошибка:

> ## github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
>
> cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

ОС Windows 8.1 x64.
Установлена версия Golang: `go version go1.9.1 windows/amd64`.

Comment: Допишите в вопрос версию и битность вашей ОС.

Comment: @Ainar-G обновил

Comment: На гитхабе сталкивались с крайне похожей проблемой: https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/297

Comment: @D-side спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить gcc порт для WIN, который поддерживает 64-бит. Возьмите, например, [здесь](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/). Укажите разрядность при инсталяции и включите новый gcc в path.